# Background with alpha channel and z-index:-1 video

Tags: android, css, z-index, alpha-transparency

Colleagues,

I embedded youtube video (autoplay, loop) under background (z-index:-1) in my website. Everything is ok when using desktop browser. But when website is opened in Android browser, youtube video isn't autoplaying. There is a play button, but I can't press it because it's under background. Is there any possibility to make that button available to press and start a video in Android or other mobile platforms?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the pertinent code here?  Why is it under the background?

Comment: For visual purposes. [Take a look](http://www.eprs.lt/temp/temp_video.png).

#background {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 721px;
    background: url(../lt/images/common/bg.png);
    position: relative;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  top: 20px;
}

...

#movie {
 position: absolute;
 z-index:-1;
 width: 304px;
 height: 228px;
}


...

<div id="movie"><iframe width="300" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NsmX1gTfqjc?&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=0&loop=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&playlist=NsmX1gTfqjc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>